# Unable to get salesorders and Customers From Magento 2.2 using REST API

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api

We have Magento Store having Version 2.2.0
Store URL:- https://www.sehrawatbrother.com
Token get through REST API:- 7mrn16lrsi51exjp563c13fdi10c0b1e
We also have created API Username and Password and assign proper Role them 
Using this token we can retrieve the products but not sales orders and customers. We are getting the error :
Array
(
    [message] => Consumer is not authorized to access %resources
    [parameters] => Array
        (
            [resources] => Magento_Sales::sales
        )

)
We have checked all the permission to resources and all are correct Still we are getting the error.